# javascript regex dollars in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some strings like these:

- "hello bla $200 bla bla"
- "hello bla $ 200 bla bla"

From where I want something like

```
"hello bla <span style='color:#0f0'>$200</span> bla bla"
```

I think I need a regex for converting those strings to the desired output but I can't create it. Help, please.
And me need status number, negative or positive and colorize it - negative red, positive green

Comment: So what have you tried? You're just asking us to write this for you?

Comment: im tried find regex for number and modify it to dollars but not success, im not strong in regex

Comment: the dollar is a special character in regex. You can find the special characters and how to use them as actual characters by doing some research. To be a bit more precise, to match an actual $ character, you need to *escape* the character (try to do some research with this terms : escape character regex)

Comment: @TrooperZ : I voted to reject your edit to turn the code into a snippet, I didn't understand it at first, sorry.

Comment: @Scott Marcus Problem in all regexps, he waiting numbers with $ and without, I’m want get only with character $ and negative status

Comment: @Pac0 it's ok. I think it's best to always use snippets for JS, CSS, and HTML unless showing half a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use...

`preg_replace("/(\$\s?\d+)/gm", "<span style='color:#0f0'>$1</span>", MyString);`

[This will help you visualize it](https://regex101.com/r/03qkD4/1/)

Comment: Pattern is correct but the tag in the question is Javascript.

Comment: What about negative or positive ?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness For some reason I thought this was tagged as PHP.

Comment: For positive/negative values, replace `(\-?\$\s?\d+)` with `<span style='color:#0f0'>$1</span>`. I believe in javascript the method you're looking for is just `string.prototype.replace()`

Comment: okey work good, but im want change color if number negative, example color:#0f0 if number positive, and color:#f00 negative, its possible ?

Comment: use two separate patterns. If it matches the negative pattern, replace with one color, else replace with the other.